# How to add text + images on Javascript button

Tags: javascript, image, button, heading

I have added an image but now I also want to add text as well as the image's heading "Responsive"

```
<script>
function pic1()
    {
        document.getElementById("img").src = "../raining.gif";
        ducument.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "<h2> Responsive </h2>";
    }
function pic2()
    {
        document.getElementById("img").src ="../movingpiston.gif";
    } 
    </script>

<img src = "" id = "img"/> 
<input type="button" value="Responsive" onclick="pic1()"/> 
<input type="button" value="Reconfiguration" onclick="pic2()"/>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo on  "ducument.getElementById" and you don't have any element with "text" as id.
Change line 5 to 
`document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "<h2> Responsive </h2>";`
and add something like `<div id="text"></div>` somewhere in your html part

Comment: i added <div id="text"></div> but it wouldn't come up "Responsive" when I click the button. The image still shows up without text

Comment: did you also change ducument by document on line 5 ?

Answer (score 0):

in ducument.getElementById("text"),where the id "text"?
do you want add a title to img that when hovering on the image it will show it's title.

text is not exists ,if you want show a text ,you need create a new element.

```html
        var img = document.getElementById("img");
        img.setAttribute("src","../raining.gif")
        var title = document.createElement("h2");
        title.innerHTML = "Responsive";
        img.parentNode.appendChild(title);
```

Comment: I want to add text and image so that when i click the button, it will come up with the text and the image shown above.

Comment: text is not exists ,if you want show a text ,you need create a new element.